# Unable to see Notebook under Notebooks Section in AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I created a new Deep Learning VM and I'm unable to see it under AI Platform Notebooks nor I can access the proxy URL.

```
gcloud compute instances create nb-2 \
 --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
 --image-family=tf2-latest-gpu \
 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE \
 --metadata="proxy-mode=service_account,install-nvidia-driver=True" \
 --boot-disk-size 300GB \
 --zone=us-west1-a
```

Serial log:

```
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> /opt/c2d/scripts/02-swap-binaries.sh, exit_code=0/SUCCESS
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> Running: /opt/c2d/scripts/03-enable-jupyter.sh
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: mount: special device /dev/sdb does not exist
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: The file /dev/sdb does not exist and no size was specified.
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: WARNING: failed to format data disk, please ignore if this is a single disk instance
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jupyter.service → /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service.
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 systemd[1]: Started Jupyter Notebook.
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> /opt/c2d/scripts/03-enable-jupyter.sh, exit_code=0/SUCCESS
May 31 06:46:26 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> Running: /opt/c2d/scripts/04-attempt-register-vm-on-proxy.sh
May 31 06:46:30 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:30.283 LabApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jupyter/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
May 31 06:46:30 nb-2 bash[1321]: [W 06:46:30.832 LabApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server will be able to run code.
May 31 06:46:31 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:31.296 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
May 31 06:46:31 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:31.297 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
May 31 06:46:31 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:31.873 LabApp] [nb_conda] enabled
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:32.488 LabApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [W 06:46:32.489 LabApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:32.489 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jupyter
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:32.490 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:32.491 LabApp] http://localhost:8080/
May 31 06:46:32 nb-2 bash[1321]: [I 06:46:32.491 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
May 31 06:46:49 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Could not fetch resource:
May 31 06:46:49 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]:  - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
May 31 06:46:49 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Proxy mode is service account with service account
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Copying gs://dl-platform-public-configs/proxy-agent-config.json...
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: / [0 files][    0.0 B/  2.5 KiB]                                                #015/ [1 files][  2.5 KiB/  2.5 KiB]
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Operation completed over 1 objects/2.5 KiB.
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: sha256:9e34ced9f64ee8efd643c60af345dcb0401f121a6d6fa3bac572c150a3010ee1: Pulling from inverting-proxy/agent
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Digest: sha256:9e34ced9f64ee8efd643c60af345dcb0401f121a6d6fa3bac572c150a3010ee1
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/inverting-proxy/agent@sha256:9e34ced9f64ee8efd643c60af345dcb0401f121a6d6fa3bac572c150a3010ee1
May 31 06:46:51 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: gcr.io/inverting-proxy/agent@sha256:9e34ced9f64ee8efd643c60af345dcb0401f121a6d6fa3bac572c150a3010ee1
May 31 06:46:52 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Proxy URL from the config: https://us-west1.notebooks.cloud.google.com/tun/m/4592f092208ecc84946b8f8f8016274df1b36a14
May 31 06:46:52 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Response from the registration server: {"backendID":"336824c42b7dbf0b","hostname":"336824c42b7dbf0b-dot-us-west1.notebooks.googleusercontent.com"}
May 31 06:46:52 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Hostname: 336824c42b7dbf0b-dot-us-west1.notebooks.googleusercontent.com
May 31 06:46:52 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Backend id: 336824c42b7dbf0b
May 31 06:46:52 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: d4d2fdc2179f2f1406e61d471c2fa9db95b332d0eb41faba44e801844fb72280
May 31 06:46:53 nb-2 containerd[669]: time="2020-05-31T06:46:53.051564534Z" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/d4d2fdc2179f2f1406e61d471c2fa9db95b332d0eb41faba44e801844fb72280/shim.sock" debug=false pid=1706
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-metadata) Could not fetch resource:
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]:  - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> /opt/c2d/scripts/04-attempt-register-vm-on-proxy.sh, exit_code=1/FAILURE
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: --> Running: /opt/c2d/scripts/05-set-metadata.sh
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Instance title: TensorFlow2.1/Keras.CUDA10.1
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Instance version: 46
May 31 06:47:14 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: Instance framework: TensorFlow:2.1
May 31 06:47:35 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-metadata) Could not fetch resource:
May 31 06:47:35 nb-2 c2d-startup[470]:  - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `scopes` when creating the instance, for example:

```
gcloud compute instances create nb-1 \
 --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
 --image-family=tf2-latest-gpu \
 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE \
 --metadata="proxy-mode=service_account,install-nvidia-driver=True" \
 --boot-disk-size 300GB \
 --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
 --zone=us-west1-a
```